# One drive for storing the File

Tags: microsoft-flow, powerapps-forms

I have a sharepoint List form which is customized in powerapps. I have used an attachment control and when ever user attaches an image i am using a flow to store that attachment in my one drive. Everything works fine here.

However if another user submits the form. Instead of storing in my one drive it is storing in his one drive. Is there any settings which i have to do in Createfile in one drive ? or this is not possible ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way OneDrive should work - it is like SharePoint my site - user-specific. If you want other users to share the file with you after submitting it from the form, file sharing should be enabled from other ends. When multiple users are working on the same files - we should go with the SharePoint document library where multiple users can work collaboratively with the same file.

However, if you want other users to access your oneDrive folder, you must share it with them before the use.

There is an open thread on this in the Microsoft Technet community, please refer to the below thread:

[Saving to someone else's OneDrive](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/onedrive-for-business/saving-to-someone-else-s-onedrive/m-p/297057)

Comment: Then what is the best way to store attachments from a sharepoint form. Even when we break inheritance once a file is added in sharepoint the sharepoint sitecollection admins can see that. Since these attachments has some sensible data and only HR people should see them not even site collection admins. Can you please guide me here

Comment: Site collection administrator is a super user for site, we can't restrict the permission for them. So, best solution would be to create a dedicated team site for HR and the owner of that site should be HR Group or some dedicated person from the HR team.... this is the recommended way to have dedicated site structure for the department.